# Is there any way to divide a progress bar into segments using swift? (as shown in the picture)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, progress, uiprogressbar

Example of segmented progress bar:

[image]

- Is there some way to duplicate this progress bar using swift.

Comment: Honestly if you're just getting started.  Simply use a horizontal UIStackView to draw the ten  squares of color.  Change each one to either red or gray.  beyond that you'd have to learn how to use CALayers in a custom UIView

Comment: Even easier if you’re using SwiftUI. If you want a SwiftUI version, I’ll gladly post an answer.

Comment: @aheze I'm searching for a segmented progress bar in SwiftUI. I would be happy if you show me your solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do this with a `UIProgressBar` but it would be trivial to create your own control that had a Float `value` property that ranged from 0 to 1 and drew a colored bar based on the value.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon
I had exactly the same question, I solved it by creating several identical vii

I created for example 7 different views with indents from each other, that's what happened[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34294078)